# Git doesn't see gpg key as secret, even though it is, how do I fix it?

Tags: git, gnupg, gpg-signature

So it seems that my gpg key is secret but when I try to sign my commits in git, it isn't recognized as secret.  I'm at a total loss for why this is.  I believe I have this setup properly but my commit signs fail.  Am I doing something wrong?  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
[brad@reason entry-criteria-test]$ gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG
/home/brad/.gnupg/secring.gpg
-----------------------------
sec   4096R/15980D34B4EED3FA 2019-03-11
uid                          Brad <brad@work.com>
ssb   4096R/3B437BF0F7366F6C 2019-03-11

[brad@reason entry-criteria-test]$ git config user.signingkey 15980D34B4EED3FA
[brad@reason entry-criteria-test]$ git config --global user.signingkey 15980D34B4EED3FA
[brad@reason entry-criteria-test]$ git commit -S -m "testing signed commit"
gpg: key B4EED3FA: secret key without public key - skipped
gpg: skipped "15980D34B4EED3FA": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
[brad@reason entry-criteria-test]$ git config -l
user.name=Brad
user.email=brad@work.com
user.signingkey=15980D34B4EED3FA
color.ui=true
push.default=simple
commit.gpgsign=true
gpg.program=gpg2
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=git@github.work.com:entry-criteria-test.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.issue-00142.remote=origin
branch.issue-00142.merge=refs/heads/issue-00142
branch.issue-00144.remote=origin
branch.issue-00144.merge=refs/heads/issue-00144
commit.gpgsign=true
user.signingkey=15980D34B4EED3FA
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was in:

```
gpg.program=gpg2
```

Even though I have gpg 2.2.13 installed, git still wants to use gpg.  This kind of makes sense as all the commands I used above for gnupg use gpg not gpg2.  So if you're having this problem check to see if your gpg2 and gpg keys are different.

```
gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG
gpg2 --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG
git config -l
```

Are these different?  Does the right key from the right gpg match your git config?

Comment: This was driving me crazy. And indeed, `git config --global gpg.program gpg2` solved the issue (though the output from `gpg` matched that from `gpg2`).

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem; I assume I must have got an update somewhere (previous key was working fine) and hadn't noticed until I came across this problem.

Comment: Thanks. The "No secret key" error came up randomly for me.  I tried what you said but my keys matched.  To fix my issue, I had to use `git config --global gpg.program gpg` and everything started working again.

Comment: Dang neither of these is fixing my issue. LONG output matches, but git continually reports it can't find the key.

Comment: Thank you, seems the issue resolved. Will moniter it. Also had to look at these points https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226944/pass-and-gpg-no-public-key