# "No secret key" error when signing git commit on Windows

Tags: windows, git, gnupg

I'm getting this error when trying to sign a commit:

```
git commit -S -m "test"
gpg: skipped "EF617ACA9EC3XXXX": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

This is the output of gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG

The key is present there

```
sec   rsa4096/EF617ACA9EC3XXXX 2020-05-17 [SC] [expires: 2022-05-17]
      AD68154000A712DCD161D826EF617ACA9EC3XXXX
uid                 [ultimate] name <email@gmail.com>
```

And this is git config with the same key

```
user.signingkey=EF617ACA9EC3XXXX
user.email=email@gmail.com
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check first the [`git config gpg.program`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-gpgprogram) to see if this is `gpg` or `gpg2` (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55126589/6309)).

And type `where gpg` nd `where gpg2` to check which path is considered for the GPG program.

I suggested to set `gpg.program` to `gpg2`, and copy your `gpg.exe` (assuming its version is a 2.x) to `gpg2.exe`

That should force Git/GPG to act as gpg2.

Comment: gpg is in git config. Path to gpg.exe is correct too, and I don't have gpg2 at all (isn't it on linux only?)

Comment: @giveall The gpg currently shipped with Git for Windows is actually a gpg 2 -2.2.17)

Comment: @giveall What version of Git for Windows are you using?

Comment: @giveall Try and set `gpg.program` to `gpg2`, and copy your `gpg.exe` (assuming its version is a 2.x) to `gpg2.exe`, for testing. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/46884134/6309

Comment: @giveall Do you have GPG4Win installed? (as in https://gist.github.com/BoGnY/f9b1be6393234537c3e247f33e74094a#gistcomment-2718488)

Comment: git 2.26.2 (the latest one, I guess?), but I still don't have gpg2 or an option to install it along with git.

Comment: Anyway, renaming gpg.exe to gpg2.exe and changing it in the config helped, which is super weird.

Comment: @giveall Strage indeed. I have edited the answer to include that recommendation.

Comment: @giveall I still suspect you had another gpg.exe installed somewhere else (as in https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1249#issuecomment-570357527). Now that `gpg.program` is set to `gpg2`, you are forced to use the Git one.

Comment: I don't think so. where gpg2 points to that gpg2.exe I just made.

Comment: @giveall Through the Git config `gpg.program`

Answer (score 39):

`git config --global gpg.program "c:/Program Files (x86)/GnuPG/bin/gpg.exe"`

I installed with Kleopatra and generated my key within that. I was unable to create a commit until I ran the command above.

Comment: I had set this before but it didn't work for me so I updated the gpg executable to `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe` and it worked.

Comment: Nicely done, when I'm using Windows 11, I use the Everything app (it's free) to search for things like the most appropriate executable.

Answer (score 14):

In case anyone is a dufus like me I was getting this error because I had the gitkey wrong while directly editing the file via: `git config --global -e` or `code ~/.gitconfig` or whatever flavor of editor you enjoy.

- `singingkey`  instead of
- `signingkey` ‍♂️

Comment: This made me laugh out loud. Thanks for that.

Comment: My case was `signinkey` instead of `signingkey`. Thank you!

Comment: This helped me today, just had to manually updated my "Key-ID" via Kleopatra

Comment: Add me to your dufus list :)

Answer (score 7):

Was facing the same issue in windows 10 git bash. Doing this solved my problem. You could find this path by running `where gpg`

> `$ git config --global gpg.program "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe"`

Answer (score 2):

I hit this issue when trying to set up git commits signing on Windows.

In my case I had multiple gpg.exe installations, including the one at `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe`. However, the default gpg command was executing a different `gpg.exe`, and generated the secret keys with it. Changing git's `gpg.program` option didn't work for me.

Ultimately, I just used git's gpg install to generate the secret key and that works like a charm:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin"
.\gpg --version
.\gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long
.\gpg --full-generate-key

etc
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Another potential issue/resolution:

Make sure the email you set in Github is verified and that it exactly matches the email you used when you generated your GPG key.

Comment: This will lead to "Unverified" on Github, not to this error. This answer is completely unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Had this same problem on Windows 11 when trying to get GitHub Desktop to work.
The answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672988/20396941) solved the issue for me:

```
git config --global gpg.program "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my issue by setting the path of the gpg.exe from git itself.

```
git config --global gpg.program "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Root-cause:**

Most probably the program used to generate the GPG keys is not the same that git is using.

**Answer (consolidated from other answers):**

1. Identify the program used to generate the GPG Keys (see next section for details).
2. Set that program to be used for commit signing in git:

```
git config --global gpg.program <path-to-the-program>
```

**GPG Key generators program locations:**

- git, git-bash: `"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe"` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672988/2751261))
- Kleopatra (x86): `"C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuPG/bin/gpg.exe"` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68958117/2751261))
- gpg2: `"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg2.exe"` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61849206/2751261))
- git installed as local user: `"C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe"` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76308888/2751261))

> **Note:** Update this answer to reflect other possible path locations so we avoid having multiple valid answers.