# Unable to Sign my commits(GPG key on windows)

Tags: git, gnupg

I am getting this error when i try to commit.

```
gpg: skipped "<My Key here>": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

My .gitconfig file.

```
[user]
    email = <my email>
    name = <My Name>
    signingkey = <The same key as before>
[gpg]
    program = C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuPG\\bin\\gpg.exe
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
```

Comment: Check first https://stackoverflow.com/a/61849206/6309

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["No secret key" error when signing git commit on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61849061/no-secret-key-error-when-signing-git-commit-on-windows)